# Are event logs still accessible after selfdestruct?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, events, logs

Are event logs still retrievable for a contract after selfdestruct?  Does fast sync or full sync in geth have any effect on this?

Basically, it looks like it would be useful to Ethereum if my contracts self-destructed after use(to remove them from the current state) but I still need to be sure I can access the logs for these contracts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logs are stored in transaction receipts. They are not removed, which means you still can access them after the selfdestruct.

Comment: Does this also hold for the events emitted in the same transaction that destructed the contract?

Comment: Yes. You‘ll have the events in the transaction log.